# handle c# web form issue where it caches browser on browser back button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, caching, webforms

I have an ASP.NET web form with a login page which directs to a new form when the authentication matches the database. This all works fine. However, the issue I am facing is if the user accidently inputs the wrong username and password, a validation error message appears. When the user goes back to enter the useranem and password and it matches, they get logged in. However, when the back button is clicked on the browser it still shows the validation error message. Although it should direct back to the login page with no error there. If the back button is pressed again, it goes back to the login page.

I tried to put some syntax in asp.net to stop caching but then I am getting "document expired" in Firefox. And "submit page for resubmission" in Chrome.

Please can someone advise?

Comment: that's just how the back button works in browsers especially if you post data from one page to the next

Comment: Is there no resolution or javascript that can resolve this except disabling the back button? I only am posting data to get past the login page, however when I press back I want it to be a "get" request and automatically send them back to the login page.

Comment: But if they press the back button once they are logged in, surely they should still be logged in and therefore only see the logged in page, rather than being taken back to re-enter their login details?

Comment: Yeah i guess so. The way I have done it is that if the username and password is incorrect, it trigges the validation message by some jquery script to remove a class which has been set in my .CSS file. Surely there must be a way to add a class when the page has been redirected to Login.aspx ? Or is there simply no way.

Comment: You can have a look at history.pushstate and see if you can push a state into the history, but it's more hassle than it's wortg

Comment: Okay thanks Pete for the help.